# Laravel does not evaluate the curly brackets when including .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a js file with the following script

```
alert("{{ route('contacts.show',':contactid:') }}");
```

I used the .js file and include it in my blade view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src={{ asset('admin/js/contact/test.js') }}></script>
```

[image: It does not evaluate the route command.]

But if I write the script in the blade view. It does evaluate the codes inside the curly brackets.

Comment: Of course, why would it. JS file is not processed by PHP.

Comment: The JS file is not a blade view.

Comment: what is the right way to add an external js file with curly brackets? so it will evaluate the code in it.

Comment: I just wanted to separate the javascript from the html. What I did now is that I added a bunch of javascripts in a blade template and include it in my main blade template so the curly brackets inside the javascript get evaluated. im pretty sure this is not the right way but so far its doing my intended purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The JS file is not processed by PHP, so the Laravel blade templates would not be in effect in the JS file. What you should do, is define the route in a variable in JS **ON THE PHP PAGE** by injecting the route value into a JS variable. Then you can access that variable in your JS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // Inject the PHP route value into a JS variable.
        window.route = '<?php echo route("contacts.show",":contactid:"); ?>';
        // You can also use 'let route = ...' to declare the variable.
    </script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
alert(route);
```

Answer (score 1):

Curly brackets are executed only when inside a blade file. If you need to keep the JS external and not merge the code into a blade template, you could define a JS variable in blade, in the global JS scope, load the external JS after it and then use that variable in your js.

in blade

```
 <script>
    var contactsRoute = ""{{ route('contacts.show',':contactid:') }}"";
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src={{ asset('admin/js/contact/test.js') }}></script>
```

In the external js

```
alert(contactsRoute);
```